# rails: connecting model with 2 other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have the following model:

```
Boys have_many relationships
Girls have_many relationships
Relationship belongs to boy
Relationship belongs to girl
```

I have the following so far:

```
  def create
    @boy = Boy.find(current_boy.id)
    @relationship = @boy.relationships.create(:relationship)
    redirect_to boy_path(@boy)
  end
```

This is my home.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@boy, @boy.relationships.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :points %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :points %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Migration file:

```
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :points
      t.references :boy
      t.references :girl

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :relationships, :boy_id
    add_index :relationships, :girl_id
  end
```

So relationships have "points." When I submit the form, I want to specify the email of the girl as well.

How do I put that as part of the form and fix the create method so when I submit this form, I create a relationship between a boy and a girl?

Many thanks.

Comment: How about boy/boy and girl/girl relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd consider having a Person (or whatever you prefer) model with a gender attribute. That'll greatly simplify the following:

Nest your resources:

```
resources :people do
  resources :relationships
end
```

Tell the model about it:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :relationships
  ...
end
```

In app/views/relationships/_form the form_for should take @person and @relationship.

Then, after a person is created they can navigate to /people/1/relationships#index where they can do all the CRUD stuff.

This is out of date but still useful: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes